# div .click function not working

Tags: jquery, click

I am trying to call a DIV .click function, but it doesn't work. The div that I'm talking about is created with PHP.

This is the result from the PHP:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:700px;" id="colorcontainer">
<div class='color' style='background: url(kleuren/c121.jpg); background-size: 100 72; background-repeat:no-repeat;'><span class='txt'>CBM 121<br />Blank Gelakt Eiken</span></div>
</div>
```

Now I try to call the div .click function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorcontainer > div').click(function() {
        var name = this.css('background-image');
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

Now it does not show the alert at all. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried it without the document.ready, with .color and all sorts of stuff, but it just doesn't call the function.

Comment: not sure why your alert isnt shown, but if you figure this one out, you have to set background-image to 'none' afaik to hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this`, it should be `$(this)`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvj9w/) is a working demo of your code.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure the use of jQuery. Use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

So

```
var name = $(this).css('background-image');
```

will work

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#colorcontainer > div').click(function() { 
        var name = $(this).css('background-image'); 
        alert(name); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorcontainer > div').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).css('background-image');
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for performance purpose you should call the div that contained the background-image like below:

```
$('.color').click(function () {
     var name = $(this).css('background-image');
     alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its long ago the post has been answered. But just in case if someone come across something similar. No doubt the answer to the above question are perfectly stated but want to share few more tips to it.(if u don't have any syntax error - Try below methods to see if click event is firing or not)
1) just below the click event, write alert and see. this ensures that nothing before the click event is wrong.
2) look if the selector you mentioned exists. here $('.color') so there should be